# kafka __consumer_offsets topic logs rapidly growing in size reducing disk space

Tags: apache-kafka

I find that the `__consumer_offsets` topic log size is growing rapidly and after studying it further found the topics with the highest volume. I changed the retention policy on these topics to stop the rate of growth but would like to increase disk space and delete all the old logs for `__consumer_offsets` topic.

But this will cause all the other topics and consumers/producers to get corrupted or lose valuable metadata. Is there a way I can accomplish this? I'm looking at the parameters for the config which includes cleanup policy and compression but not sure how to specify this specifically for the topics that caused this rapid growth.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html

Appreciate any assistance here.

Comment: what do you mean with "high volume". Are we talking about hundreds of MB or GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kafka, there are two types of log retention; *size* and *time* retention. The former is triggered by `log.retention.bytes` while the latter by `log.retention.hours`.

In your case, you should pay attention to *size* retention that sometimes can be quite tricky to configure. Assuming that you want a `delete` cleanup policy, you'd need to configure the following parameters to

```
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleanup.policy=delete
```

Then you need to think about the configuration of `log.retention.bytes`, `log.segment.bytes` and `log.retention.check.interval.ms`. To do so, you have to take into consideration the following factors:

- `log.retention.bytes` is a minimum guarantee for a **single partition of a topic**, meaning that if you set `log.retention.bytes` to 512MB, it means you will always have 512MB of data (per partition) in your disk.
- Again, if you set `log.retention.bytes` to 512MB  and `log.retention.check.interval.ms` to 5 minutes (which is the default value) at any given time, you will have *at least* 512MB of data + the size of data produced within the 5 minute window, before the retention policy is triggered.
- A topic log on disk, is made up of segments. The segment size is dependent to `log.segment.bytes` parameter. For `log.retention.bytes=1GB` and `log.segment.bytes=512MB`, you will always have up to 3 segments on the disk (2 segments which reach the retention and the 3rd one will be the active segment where data is currently written to).

Finally, you should do the math and compute the maximum size that might be reserved by Kafka logs at any given time on your disk and tune the aforementioned parameters accordingly. Of course, I would also advice to set a time retention policy as well and configure `log.retention.hours` accordingly. If after 2 days you don't need your data anymore, then set `log.retention.hours=48`.

---

Now in order to change the retention policy just for the `__consumer_offsets` topic, you can simply run:

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh \
    --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --alter \
    --entity-type topics \
    --entity-name __consumer_offsets \
    --add-config retention.bytes=...
```

---

As a side note, you must be very careful with the retention policy for the `__consumer_offsets` as this might mess up all your consumers.

Comment: If I understand it correctly question is about the topic __consumer_offsets. In that case it will be very dangerous to change the retention.bytes. Imagine you have a consumer C1 reading data from a topic and then this consumer is paused for a longer period and only other consumers are active. When the one consumer C1 gets active again, it could be the case that the offsets for C1 are already cleaned...

Comment: @mike I agree with you and this is exactly what I mentioned in the end of my post. However, it is still possible and feasible assuming that the retention policy will satisfy his requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. That's exactly me concern if I were to change the consumer_offsets topic. I understand the changes on the other topics will reduce those log sizes going forward but also wondered how to remove the old logs so that I start with lower disk space instead of 80% usage where it is now. Cannot get additional physical storage right now.

Comment: @user1585245 You don't have to delete anything manually. If you configure your retention policy accordingly, it might be effective straight away.

Comment: Ok so from researching this I think cleanupLogs method may help..need to figure out how this is done but are either of you familiar with this?

Comment: In general I would agree with answer from @GiorgosMyrianthous, but as this topic is very sensitive I put another suggestions that could help you out here.

Answer (score 3):

The topic "__consumer_offsets" is an internal topic which is used to manage the offsets of each Consumer Group. Producers will not be directly impacted by any change/modification in this topic.

Saying that, and also emphasizing your expecrience, you should be very careful about changing the configuration of this topic.

I suggest to tweak the topic configurations for compacted topics. The cleanup policy should be kept at "compacted".

Reduce `max.compaction.lag.ms` (cluster-wide setting: `log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms`) which defaults to MAX_LONG to something like 60000.

Reduce the ratio when a compaction is triggered through `min.cleanable.dirty.ratio` (cluster-wide setting: `log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio`) which defaults to 0.5 to something like 0.1.

That way, the compactions will be conducted more often without loosing any essential information.

#### Deleting old records in __consumer_offsets

The topic will pile up if you use many unique Consumer Groups (e.g. by using console-consumer which creates by default a random Consumer Group each time it is being executing).

To clean "old and un-needed" entries in the topic you need to be aware how to delete a message out of a *compacted* topic. This is done by producing a message to the topic with a `null` value. That way you will eventually delete the messages for the same key. You just have to figure out the keys of the messages you want to get rid of.