# __consumer_offsets topic growing huge

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any way we can track cleanup on the consumer_offsets topic? I m trying to find where the throttle is.

The problem is consumer_offsets topic right now is over 400 GB. It happens quite frequently and we had to adjust the log.cleaner.threads between 2 - 4 to kick the compaction. We have been doing this once every week to reduce the size of the consumer_offsets topic. We are using Kafka 1.1 version.

I m trying to find where the throttle is, if its capacity issue or if the log cleaner thread is being blocked by something. Any tools to debug this problem?

Can someone shed light on this? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kafka \_\_consumer\_offsets topic logs rapidly growing in size reducing disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956217/kafka-consumer-offsets-topic-logs-rapidly-growing-in-size-reducing-disk-space)

Comment: How many consumer groups do you have? Sometimes, we need to ensure that if our applications are *using* a group.id, rather than *generating* a unique consumer `group.id`

Comment: config on the brokers: 
log.cleaner.backoff.ms=15000
log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=524288000
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor=0.9
log.cleaner.io.buffer.size=1048576
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5
log.cleaner.threads=2
log.cleanup.policy=delete
log.delete.delay.ms=60000
log.index.interval.bytes=4096
log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760
log.message.format.version=1.1
log.retention.bytes=-1
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.retention.hours=168
log.roll.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
`

Comment: We have around 4000 consumer groups on this cluster. Can you please elaborate more on the applications using group.id? May be that's something I need to look into

Comment: If you are having 4000 consumer groups, offsets for each topic partition in each consumer group has to be tracked, so more the consumer groups, more will be total no. of tracked offsets. Consider, each consumer group has 1 topic with 3 partitions, then in Kafka, there will be 4000*1*3 = 12000 consumer offsets stored.

Comment: 4000 looks like a big number, are you having 4000 'different' *"applications"* (not instances) using your Kafka cluster? At what scale are you running it?

Comment: weird, I thought I added my comments here last week. 
  So we found a bug in one of the applications where random consumer groups are being generated and fixed it.Now the consumer groups are down to ~350. However, the consumer_offsets still growing. 
 We updated the cleaner_threads configuration to kick off compaction last week and it came down to 25GB from 400 GB. Its going back up again, now its at 50 GB. So something definitely wrong here.
 we have 5 brokers, 500 topics, probably under 750 GB used storage

Comment: @crisptech hello, I have a similar problem: 50 consumer group, 50 topics and 100 partitions. The __consumer_offsets topic is 3TB. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Hey, our problem was solved after we upgraded to kafka 2.4.1 version. What version you are running on? Try a restart of the brokers if you already have above configs