# Why does Kafka Topic __consumer_offsets has unbalanced size in partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka 2.0.0.

In the **__consumer_offset** topic, the most of partitions are 30MB, but some partitions are very big. For example: 1 partition is 15GB, another partition is 250GB, etc.

What could be the problem?

Comment: is the log compaction enabled for `__consumer_offset`?

Answer (score 1):

The topic `__consumer_offsets` stores the latest committed offset for each subscribed TopicPartition of a Kafka Consumer Group. In this topic the ConsumerGroup servers as the key.

Apparently, your ConsumerGroups which fall into the same partition (applying the hash(key) % #partitions logic) are much more active (consuming more messages more frequently) compared to other Consumer Groups.

Comment: Is there a way to have more balanced partitions for that topic? Thanks :)

Comment: The only thing I can imagine would be to have more diverse ConsumerGroup names. Otherwise, I do not see any other option here. If the size becomes too big you could have a look in [kafka __consumer_offsets topic logs rapidly growing in size reducing disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956217/kafka-consumer-offsets-topic-logs-rapidly-growing-in-size-reducing-disk-space/61957100#61957100)

Comment: Another option is to [Kafka: Delete idle consumer group id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137375/kafka-delete-idle-consumer-group-id)

Comment: Could be also a problem of kafka 2.0.0? Maybe upgrading the cluster with the new version of kafka could be solution? Thanks :)

Comment: I do not think so. The logic to distribute messages across partitions within a topic did not change over time.

Comment: I also noticed that some partitions of that topic, contain hundreds of .log .index files instead of only 2. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, this is normal because you have a different size in the partitions.